# DateFormatter showing different date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am new to iOS and I want to add some milliseconds say (5) to my date. I have used the below code but I am not getting the exact date which I am using

```
let str_TimeStamp = "2017-08-09 10:26:30.8"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")! as TimeZone

var dateInput: Date? = formatter.date(from: str_TimeStamp)
dateInput = dateInput?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(5*100))
let endtime = formatter.string(from: dateInput!)
print(endtime)
```

I am getting the output having some delay of mins

> 2017-08-09 10:28:10.8

Comment: Unrelated, but you should eliminate the use of `NSTimeZone`. Just instantiate `TimeZone` directly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The parameter of the `addingTimeInterval` is the value to add, in
>   **seconds**.

So, `addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(5*100))` - adds 500 seconds = 8 minutes.

If you want to add some milliseconds say (5), you should add this time interval: 0.005

So, the final code is:

```
let str_TimeStamp = "2017-08-09 10:26:30.8"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

var dateInput = formatter.date(from: str_TimeStamp)
dateInput = dateInput?.addingTimeInterval(5/1000)

if let dateInput = dateInput {
    let endtime = formatter.string(from: dateInput)
    print(endtime) // prints 2017-08-09 10:26:30.8050
}
```

Comment: Note that if the date string doesn't contain the time zone it usually means that it is local time. Don't change the timezone when parsing the date string  unless you are sure that that date it is not local time.

Comment: @LeoDabus - I disagree that in the absence of a time zone that it "usually means" local time. (I'd actually contend that when dealing with web services and persistent stores, the exact opposite is true.) But I agree that in the absence of a specific timezone qualifier in the string, you must confirm what time zone should be used.